# Як перекласти "permutation symbol"

Tags: from-english, вибір-слова

Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики 2010р. (Є. Мейнарович, М. Кратко) має [такий запис](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=permutation&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> **permutation** = [ˌpɜ:mju'teɪʃn] пере́ставка, переста́ва, перестано́вка; переставля́ння/переста́влення; пермута́ція
> • **circular** ~ = колова́ (циклі́чна) пере́ставка
> • **complete** ~ = по́вна пере́ставка
> • **cyclic** ~ = циклі́чна пере́ставка
> • **even** ~ = па́рна пере́ставка
> ...

Мені потрібно перекласти *permutation symbol* і я не знаю який варіант перекладу слова *permutation* обрати.

#### Означення

[image]

або інакше
[image]

У коментарях було пролунало запитання щодо того, чи не те саме це, що й [символ Леві-Чивіти](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96-%D0%A7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8). Відповідь - не завжди. Символ Леві-Чивіти -- це тензор, а символ перестановки/переставки - ні, і вони тотожні не в усіх системах координат. Це можна прочитати в розділі [Означення](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96-%D0%A7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.9E.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F).

Comment: Це про [символ Леві-Чивіти](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Символ_Леві-Чивіти)? («[Levi-Civita symbol](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) <…> Other names include the permutation symbol, antisymmetric symbol, or alternating symbol, which refer to its antisymmetric property and definition in terms of permutations.»)

Comment: @Sasha Ну, так, але річ у тім, що символ Леві-Чивіти збігається із символом перестановки/переставки лише якщо визначник метричного тензора дорівнює одиниці. Ця умова виконується, наприклад, в декартових координатах.

Comment: Докладно не заглиблювався, але склалося враження (по [цьому](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) і [цьому](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationSymbol.html)), що це просто різні назви одного й того самого — потім ще перечитаю.

Comment: Однозначно знак перестановки. Саме такий термін можна знайти у багатьох українських книжках з дискретної математики чи алгебри. По суті, наведене вами означення на основі парності перестановки (точніше, числа інверсій) визначає її ЗНАК (-1,+1 чи 0).

Answer (score 1):

*Хм*, як вже написали у коментарях до питання, це просто **знак перестановки**. Цікаво, що містяться у наведених там посиланнях [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) та [2](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationSymbol.html) слова щодо можливої рівності понять символу Леві-Чевіти та знаку перестановки, але, мабуть, у відповідній літературі зазвичай використовують таке **виключно** для декартових. Не знаю, просто у декартових все простіше, зазвичай. *Серед таких речей, звичайно. То моя думка на зараз.

Остаточно, ще раз: this "permutation symbol" — definitely the "знак перестановки".

P. S. Вже згадані у тексті посилання [3](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%96-%D0%A7%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B8#.D0.9E.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F) та [[4, Three dim.]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Definition) both are the great illustrations. :-)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).